# How to escape id containing <b>

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, escaping

I'm trying to escape this (German) `id` CSS selector in jQuery (note the `<b>`):

```
$('[id="fa_form_row_<b>Wer ist der teilnehmer/in (Mehrfachantworten möglich)?</b> des Kurses:"]').toggleClass('inactive');
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why is THAT an id?

Comment: Invalid indentifer, take a step back and think why do you need such an `id`.

Comment: @Lambda Ninja: Horribly broken server-side software is one reason I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use (double) backslashes:

```
$('[id="fa_form_row_\\<b\\>Wer ist der teilnehmer/in (Mehrfachantworten möglich)?\\</b\\> des Kurses:"]').toggleClass('inactive');
```

<sup>(Source: [CSS Tricks](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/))</sup>

---

Also check out [`CSS.escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape), an **experimental** technology that has some support in Chrome and Firefox:

```
var selector = CSS.escape('[id="fa_form_row_<b>Wer ist der teilnehmer/in (Mehrfachantworten möglich)?</b> des Kurses:"]');
$(selector).toggleClass('inactive');
```

Comment: CSS.escape() won't do anything useful here. The given selector is valid CSS and does not need any backslash escapes whatsoever. The reason it doesn't work in jQuery is because jQuery is interpreting it as something other than a selector. I don't know if the asker managed to get this to work, but in my testing, backslash escaping doesn't change how the string is interpreted by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can do this, *you shouldn't*. As you can see from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), the `id` attribute cannot contain these some of the characters you already have:

> This attribute's value must not contain whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.).

And:

> Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.

The [official HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) confirms this:

> The value must not contain any space characters.

And for [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Totally agree. This id value is very impractical and wrong if not for HTML5's leniency.

Comment: MDN is not the HTML spec.

Comment: @BoltClock I know, I was going to come back to this and fix it (but work interrupted...)